# Compressing an int Binary array of any random length of 1's and 0's

Tags: binary, huffman-code

Can an Array containing only Binary numbers be condensed ? For example finding number of intervals of consecutive 1's and 0's in the int array and then using the intervals we can find the maximum and minimum interval of consecutive 1's and 0's ?

Finding shortest interval of consecutive 1's and 0's is possible but how can we find all the consecutive 1's and 0's interval ? We do not need intervals for bit pattern like which is not consecutive 1's or 0's.

Comment: "Can an Array containing only Binary numbers be condensed?" Sure. Google "run length encoding" for a start. Google "compression algorithms" for more research. The trick is just making sure that your chosen method doesn't result in an increase in size on average.

Comment: I'm confused. To me, the _shortest_ interval of consecutive 1's [or 0's] is _one_ (e.g. `10...` or `01...`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But using run length encoding is it possible we can also find the intervals in which we have consecutive bit pattern for 1 or 0 ? Like if I have 1's 100 times consecutive and at 101 we will have a zero. Now how do we again find the consecutive 1's bit pattern as we not sure of it's as it's length as it's an int and how many consecutive 1's we can have is also not known

Comment: The signal I am using will not give an output if I have 10 or 01 need to have at least 2 consecutive 1's or 0's to count it as an interval. I need to found all these possible intervals to condense them and using the condensed array I need to translate it but I don't know how is it possible to do it without knowing data as it will be randomly generated and can contain any pattern of consecutive 1's or 0's